# MVC o método que usei para chamar uma função de outro model está correto?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou estudando MVC e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma View que precisa receber dados de dois Models diferentes, então no controller desta View eu tenho a função abaixo:

```
public function teste($id) {

        $this->view->a = $this->getOneA($id);
        
        $this->loadModel('b');
        $this->view->b = $this->model->getOneB($id);

        $this->view->render('app/teste');
}
```

O cenário acima me retorna o esperado, pega os dados de A e de B e os deixa disponiveis para a View.

Está correto utilizar esse método ?

Se sim, eu deveria carregar o Model "b" no __construct do controller "a"  ou diretamente na função do controller "a" como neste exemplo?

Se não, qual a melhor maneira de obter dados de diferentes Models?

OBS: todos os controllers são filhos do controller principal e todos os models são filhos do model principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Está correto utilizar esse método ?
> Se sim, eu deveria carregar o Model "b" no __construct do controller "a" ou diretamente na função do controller "a" como neste exemplo?

Para quem passar pela mesma dúvida, a resposta é Sim para as perguntas acima.

Posso declarar o model tanto no construct (possibilitando a utilização em qualquer lugar da classe) quanto em uma única função como no exemplo.

A estrutura é bem parecida (inclusive os nomes dos métodos) com a do CakePHP.

Encontrei aqui a resposta https://riptutorial.com/cakephp/example/11485/load-another-model-into-controller